# Form action attribute not working with js script

Tags: javascript, php, html

I wrote a simple register form with an action attribute on HTML that when the user fills the inputs
it sends them to my database. Everything works fine until I added a validation script using Javascript. The script works fine with my parameters but when I press the submit button the form doesnt execute the action attribute. One way I thought around this is make a simpler script inside my HTML but I'd prefer to keep it on a separate file.

HTML:

```
                <script defer src = "validation.js">
            .......
                   <form action="register_user.php" method="post" id="formRegister" name = "formRegister" >

                     <div class="formfield">
                      <table style="display: inline-table; margin: 0px 12px 0px 12px;" >
                         <tr>
                            <td> Name<b style="color:red;">*</b> </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class = "input-control">
                               <input type="text" name="name" size="32" id="name"  >
                               <div class="error"></div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                         </tr>

                         <tr>
                            <td> Surename<b style="color:red;">*</b> </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class = "input-control">
                               <input type="text" name="surename" size="32"  id="surename" >
                               <div class="error"></div>
                            </div>
                           </td>
                         </tr>

                         <tr>
                            
                            <td> AMKA<b style="color:red;">*</b> </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class = "input-control">
                               <input type="text" name="amka" size="32"  id="amka" >
                               <div class="error"></div>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                         </tr>

                         <tr>
                            <td> AFM<b style="color:red;">*</b> </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class = "input-control">
                               <input type="text" name="afm" size="32"  id="afm" >
                               <div class="error"></div>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                         </tr>

                         <tr>
                            <td> PID<b style="color:red;">*</b> </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class = "input-control">
                               <input type="text" name="pid" size="32"  id="pid">
                               <div class="error"></div>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                         </tr>

                         <tr>
                            <td> Age<b style="color:red;">*</b> </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class = "input-control">
                               <input type="text" name="age" size="32"  id="age">
                               <div class="error"></div>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                         </tr>

                         <tr>
                            <td> Gender </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class = "input-control">
                               <input type="text" name="gender" size="32">
                                <div class = "error"></div>
                               </div>
                            </td>
                         </tr>

                         <tr>
                            <td> Email </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class = "input-control">
                               <input type="text" name="email" size="32" id = "email">
                               <div class="error"></div>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                         </tr>

                         <tr>
                            <td> Mobile Phone<b style="color:red;">*</b> </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class = "input-control">
                               <input type="text" name="mphone" size="32"  id="mphone">
                               <div class="error"></div>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                         </tr>

                        <tr>
                    <td> Role<b style="color:red;">*</b> </td>

                         <td>
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <div class = "input-control">
                             <select  id="dropdown" name = "dropdown">
                                 <option value= "">Select...</option>
                                 <option value="1">Civilian</option>
                                 <option value="2">Doc</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class="error"></div>
                             </div>
                              </div>
            </td>
                   </tr>

                      </table>

                      <br><br>

                      <button type="submit" name="register" > Register </button>

                     </div>

                   </form>
```

Javascript (validation.js):

```
const formRegister = document.getElementById('formRegister');
const nameid = document.getElementById('name');
const surename = document.getElementById('surename');
const amka = document.getElementById('amka');
const afm = document.getElementById('afm');
const pid = document.getElementById('pid');
const age = document.getElementById('age');
const mphone = document.getElementById('mphone');
const dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
const email = document.getElementById('email');

formRegister.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    validateInputs();
});

const setError = (element, message) => {
    const inputControl = element.parentElement;
    const errorDisplay = inputControl.querySelector('.error');

    errorDisplay.innerText = message;
    inputControl.classList.add('error');
    inputControl.classList.remove('success')
}

const setSuccess = element => {
    const inputControl = element.parentElement;
    const errorDisplay = inputControl.querySelector('.error');

    errorDisplay.innerText = '';
    inputControl.classList.add('success');
    inputControl.classList.remove('error');
};

const isValidEmail = email => {
    const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}


const validateInputs = () => {
    const nameidValue = nameid.value.trim();
    const surenameValue = surename.value.trim();
    const amkaValue = amka.value.trim();
    const afmValue = afm.value.trim();
    const pidValue = pid.value.trim();
    const ageValue = age.value.trim();
    const mphoneValue = mphone.value.trim();
    const dropdownValue = dropdown.value;
    const emailValue = email.value.trim();



var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
var symbols = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]+/;
var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
//error check
//name
if (nameidValue === ''){
    setError(nameid, 'Error');
}else if(nameidValue.match(letters)){
    setSuccess(nameid);
}else{
    setError(nameid, 'Error');
}
//surename
if (surenameValue === '' ){
    setError(surename, 'Error');
}else if (surenameValue.match(letters)){
    setSuccess(surename);
}else{
    setError(surename, 'Error');
}
//amka
if (amkaValue === ''){
    setError(amka, 'Error');
}else if(amkaValue.length != 11){
    setError(amka,'Error');
}else{
    setSuccess(amka);
}
//afm
if (afmValue === ''){
    setError(afm, 'Error');
}else if(afmValue.length != 9){
    setError(afm,'Error');
}else {
    setSuccess(afm);
}
//pid
if (pidValue === ''){
    setError(pid,'Error');
}else if(pidValue.length != 8){
    setError(pid, 'Error');
}else{
    setSuccess(pid);
}
//age


if (ageValue === ''){
    setError(age, 'Error');
}else {
    setSuccess(age);
}


//mphone
if (mphoneValue === ''){
    setError(mphone,'Error');
}else if(mphoneValue.length != 10){
    setError(mphone, 'Error')
}else {
    setSuccess(mphone);
}
//dropdown
if (dropdownValue == ""){
    setError(dropdown, 'Error');
}else{
    setSuccess(dropdown);
}

    
};
```

Comment: You are missing some `/` to close your `<input>` tags.

Comment: Input tags no longer require the `/` to close them.

Comment: Ok, just googled it. Did not know that, as my linter shows errors if they are not closed. But it seems they only need to be closed when using XHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't submit the form due to this line:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

My suggestion is you resubmit the form after your validation logic has run providing the form is valid.

Comment: Thanks that actually worked. Ill try to work my way around to find another way for my form to not submit while every field is empty!

Comment: If you add an id to your button you can manually call the button to submit after your validation has run.

Answer (score 0):

You're preventing the default action of the browser to submit the post request to the given route.
Try removing the "e.preventDefault" from the script.js. That should send the data to the route

Comment: Yeah I'll try to find my way around it somehow. But thats what it keeps it from using the action attribute.